# To find secret word from a list?

Tags: python, recursion

I have to find secret word from a list using a function isIn(secretWord,lettersGuessed). Posting my code below.

```
def isWordGuessed(secretWord, lettersGuessed):

    if secretWord=="" or lettersGuessed==[]:
        return False
    if secretWord[0:] in lettersGuessed:
     return True
    else:
     return isWordGuessed(secretWord[1:],lettersGuessed)
```

For some examples, I am getting wrong answers. Some of them are:

```
isWordGuessed('apple', ['a', 'e', 'i', 'k', 'p', 'r', 's'])
```

In the above example, I got `True` as output which should have been `False` as once a letter of secretWord is guessed correct in the lettersGuessed it should exclude it for the second recursion. I need to know if there is a way to exclude the letter guessed once from the list lettersGuessed.

Thanks

P.S. I got the solution for this but with a different code in a similar question asked here, but to learn I need to know where I went wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few fixes:

```
>>> def isWordGuessed(secretWord, lettersGuessed):
...         if secretWord=="" or lettersGuessed==[]:
...             return False
            # secretWord[0:] picks whole word not a single character so replace with secretWord[0]
            # also flip the condition
...         if secretWord[0] not in lettersGuessed:  
...             return False
            # an extra check for the last word otherwise it would do one more recursion and return false by condition 1
...         if len(secretWord)==1 and secretWord in lettersGuessed:  
...             return True
...         else:
...             return isWordGuessed(secretWord[1:],lettersGuessed)
... 
>>> isWordGuessed('apple', ['a', 'e', 'i', 'k', 'p', 'r', 's'])
False
>>> isWordGuessed('apple', ['a', 'e', 'i', 'l', 'p', 'r', 's'])
True
```

Answer (score 2):

Break it down condition by condition:

```
if secretWord=="" or lettersGuessed==[]:
    return False
```

If its empty, then return false. Seems simple enough.

```
if secretWord[0:] in lettersGuessed:
 return True
```

If the first letter is in secret word, return True. Ok, lets look at the call:

```
isWordGuessed('apple', ['a', 'e', 'i', 'k', 'p', 'r', 's'])
```

Well, neither `secretWord` or `lettersGuessed` are empty, so we go to the second condition.

Since the first letter of `apple` is in the guessed letters, the function returns True - hence the error.

---

edit: Someone has pointed out that `secretWord[0:]` gets the whole word, which doesn't explain why it sometimes works. The reason is actually similar to above, but in reverse.

The second condition, will only ever be called with the *last* letter,

Since `apple`,`pple`,`ple`,and `le` aren't in `lettersGuessed` the final check, of `'e' in lettersGuessed` will return false. So any call where the last letter is in the array will return True.

---

What you want is this:

```
def isWordGuessed(secretWord, lettersGuessed):

    if secretWord=="" or lettersGuessed==[]:
        return False
    else:
     return secretWord[0] in lettersGuessed and isWordGuessed(secretWord[1:],lettersGuessed)
```

Because you need the first letter to be in `lettersGuessed` as well as for the rest of the letters to be in there as well.

Comment: Ok..so how should I improve it? shouldn't use `in` ?

Comment: Ya, got it..But it's showing False for this example but  `isWordGuessed('durian', ['h', 'a', 'c', 'd', 'i', 'm', 'n', 'r', 't', 'u'])` but it should be True.

Comment: Ya, you are right maybe there is some problem with eDx code interpreter.

Comment: [http://www.pythontutor.com/visualize.html#togetherjs=pnnOBO1f45] I got it False in my shell even in online python tutor.